# Exportar un archivo de PowerPoint a PDF con Visual Basic VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, visual-basic, powerpoint

estoy realizando un boton desde excel que lo que quiero que realice es pasar los datos de una tabla a una presentacion de powerpoint tipo correspondencia y que de ahi lo convierta en PDF. Al momento de pasar los datos de excel a power point todo excelente, pero al querer convertirlo a PDF me genera error, aqui les dejo el codigo:

```
    Dim objPPT As Object
    Dim objPres As Object
    
    
    
    Set objPPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    objPPT.Visible = True
    Set objPres = objPPT.presentations.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\contratosListos.pptx")
    
    ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & ActivePresentation.Name & ".pdf", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint
```

Por favor Ayudaa

Comment: ¿Qué línea te da el error? Posiblemente tengas que sustituir las constantes `ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint` por su valor numérico para ejecutarlo desde Excel

Comment: Esta linea `ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & ActivePresentation.Name & ".pdf", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrin` Supongo que es porque la macro al estoy ejecutando desde excel, pero, como podria hacer para que aun desde excel me convierta ese archivo nuevo generado en PDF?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error exacto que te da? Aun así, mira el primer comentario que puse: busca los equivalentes numéricos de tus constantes y prueba

Comment: ... y usando `objPres` en vez de `ActivePresentation`

Answer (score 2):

Cada suite ofimática de Office tiene sus propias clases y objetos en VBA, así como sus propias constantes. Por ejemplo, desde VBA de Powerpoint no puedes llamar a la clase `Range` porque no está en su jerarquía.

Es cierto que cuando ejecutas un `CreateObject` creas una instancia de dicha suite, pero como estás utilizando *late binding* en vez de *early binding* no te reconoce las constantes propias de Powerpoint.

Hablamos de *late binding* cuando se trata de **Enlace en tiempo de ejecución** y hablamos de *early binding* cuando se trata de **Enlace anticipado**.

Puedes encontrar información detallada de esto aquí (**muy recomendable su lectura**):

> [Uso del enlace anticipado y el enlace en tiempo de ejecución en
> Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients)

Bien, en tu caso estás usando *late binding* así que VBA de Excel no reconoce las constantes `ppFixedFormatTypePDF` ni `ppFixedFormatIntentPrint`, pero ambas tienen un valor numérico asociado (a esto se le llama *Enumeration*):

> [Enumeración PpFixedFormatType
> (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppfixedformattype)
>
> [Enumeración PpFixedFormatIntent
> (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppfixedformatintent)

Tras consultar las fuentes, tu código debería ser algo así:

```
Dim objPPT As Object
Dim objPres As Object

Set objPPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
objPPT.Visible = True
Set objPres = objPPT.presentations.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\contratosListos.pptx")

objPres.ExportAsFixedFormat objPres.Path & "\" & objPres.Name & ".pdf", 2, 2
```